# how to hash a password laravel 5.2 model create

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating admin user via model and it saving record successfully but password is not being hashed as follows:

```
$request->password = bcrypt($request->input('password'));
    Admin::create($request->except('_token'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not modify $request properties like that.

Give it a try:

```
$input = $request->except('_token');
$input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

Admin::create($input);
```

OR, handle it in your Admin Model

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($value);
}
```

Then you can

```
Admin::create($request->except('_token'));
```

Comment: it throughs Function name must be a string

Comment: @MuhammadMuazzam Updated.

Comment: I can not brief it anymore. All three lines are necessary!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Laravel's [Hashing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/hashing). It shows that you should be hashing any strings like so:

```
Hash::make($request->newPassword)
```

However looking at your code, i'd say this issue is actually the fact you're trying to modify the request `$request->password`, this is not going to work how you expect. Look at your Admin model class and see what the code is expecting, perhaps this is already in built if you pass the correct arguments.